# CSS animation problems with IE8, works fine in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, css, animation, internet-explorer-8, margin

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/ehohi4/10

Click on a year to collapse/expand a section. In all modern browsers plus IE6 and IE7, it works fine, but in IE8, try clicking on 2008 a few times, and sometimes the margin-bottom:100px is gone when the section is collapsed, but the browser still returns that it has a marginBottom of 100px, as shown in the debug message on the bottom.

Is this an IE8 problem that have to be accepted or might this be a jQuery 1.5.2 problem?

Edit: Video of bug in action (and how I worked around it)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqqiLBrHwbo

Comment: No amount of slow clicking can make the "bug" happen for me. I have to spam click on 2008/2009, and then it happens - sometimes.

Comment: I tried it- nothing seems to change it all looks ok. I clicked it many many times..

Comment: Jeez- how fast were you clicking man? i nearly broked my mouse and it still works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it with various older versions of jQuery and the same problem is still there, I think this is a IE8 rendering problem. Ugh, IE8 is the new IE6... Ended up removing the margin-bottom for that div and adding a 100px high div instead, specifically for IE8.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqqiLBrHwbo

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work ok for me.  Are you using IE8 or IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode?

Try fixing the margin error specifically.

```
$('.award_year').click(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle',
        marginBottom: 100
    }, 400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use IE8 on Windows XP for testing. The 100px bottom margin is for <div class="award">.